# Rails aws::s3 question: How do I get a url/link to a kml file stored in S3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, url, amazon-s3, kml

I have a rails app that creates a kml file and successfully loads it to s3.  I can't figure out how to get that file back out as a usable link.  Nothing fancy. It would be nice to control the appearance of the url, but I'm looking for the simplest solution.

Specifically, when I attempt to do this in the controller with a

```
render myS3Object.value, :layout => false
```

I get a "Template missing" error page (which does include the file's text) in my browser, and a "file not found" in Google Earth.

When I use

```
redirect_to myS3Object.url(:authenticated => false)
```

I get

```
<Error>
<Code>AccessDenied</Code>
<Message>Access Denied</Message>
<RequestId>blar</RequestId>
<HostId>blar</HostId>
</Error>
```

in the browser, and another "file not found" in Google Earth.

I also tried url_for, and setting expires for 3 hours in the future, with no luck.

BTW, I have the Mime type specified in my mimes file, and restarted the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked, for the most part:

```
send_data myS3Object.value
```